# Best open source Java library to incorporate Facebook functionality into a Java web app?

Tags: java, web-applications, open-source, facebook

What's the best open source Java library to add Facebook functionality to a Java web app?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since facebook stopped supporting a Java API, the mantle of trying to provide one has been taken up by a google coding group:

http://code.google.com/p/facebook-java-api/

The API is provided under the [MIT License](http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php).

Comment: Project is discontinued.  They recommend RestFB.

Answer (score 10):

For the simplest and most updated API, I'm liking RestFB so far.

http://restfb.com/

Comment: I check restfb and its good and easy.
But when icheck it on [Github](https://github.com/revetkn/restfb) there no updates from last one month.
and there are many issues open in restfb [github issues](https://github.com/revetkn/restfb/issues).
So there are any API which is active and better then restfb.

Answer (score 2):

This is by far the most advanced option if your technical chops are up to it:

http://code.google.com/p/batchfb/

It will automatically batch multiple requests so you don't have to think about it.  BatchFB will even execute them in parallel if you overflow the maximum batch size and you're on a platform that supports asynchronous fetching (like App Engine).